# I cant return my home.html with spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, controller

[image]

This picture pretty much describes my entire code, and project structure.
The problem i can't return home.html file in the static folder. I tried with home, **home.html**, both ways just don't work.

Now I just want to say that i am able to return the index.html file, but not the other one. What's happening here exactly?

Comment: As the error says, the "server" is looking for a home.html in the template folder...

Comment: ye ik, how to make it look for it somewhere else?

Comment: first i would try to copy the existing home.html to the templates folder and see if that works.

Comment: it works but i want it to be in the static folder...

Comment: and why ? you could start an build a folder system in the templates folder (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: you are technically right, but in this case my entire code was 10 lines from witch 5 where brackets and new lines, i had to show the entire project structure, cause it was related to the question and i had to show my error. This picture describes it all perfeclty. The other option was not to post a picture and write 50 lines description in the question and it would have been much harder for them to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Use `@RestController`  instead of `@Controller`. Show us the code, What is the error in console?

Comment: the error is discribed in the screenshot `Error resolving template "home.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: In your console of the IJ, there is an error displayed. please show that to us.

Comment: your right side bottom window is the console window, show us the error